# Configuring Oracle Listener in OpenSuse Leap 15.0

Tags: opensuse, oracle18c

Having trouble getting Oracle XE 18c installed on OpenSuse Leap 15.0... When running the configuration script:

```
joshua@linux-t1zu:~> sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe-18c configure
[sudo] password for root: 
/bin/df: unrecognized option '--direct'
Try '/bin/df --help' for more information.
Specify a password to be used for database accounts. Oracle recommends that the password entered should be at least 8 characters in length, contain at least 1 uppercase character, 1 lower case character and 1 digit [0-9]. Note that the same password will be used for SYS, SYSTEM and PDBADMIN accounts:
Confirm the password:
Configuring Oracle Listener.
Listener configuration failed. Check log '/opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/netca/netca_configure_out.log' for more details.
```

Here are the contents of the

```
/opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/netca/netca_configure_out.log

joshua@linux-t1zu:~> cat /opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/netca/netca_configure_out.log 

Parsing command line arguments:
    Parameter "orahome" = /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE
    Parameter "instype" = typical
    Parameter "inscomp" = client,oraclenet,javavm,server,ano
    Parameter "insprtcl" = tcp
    Parameter "cfg" = local
    Parameter "authadp" = NO_VALUE
    Parameter "responsefile" = /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/network/install/netca_typ.rsp
    Parameter "silent" = true
    Parameter "orahnam" = OraHomeXE
    Parameter "listenerparameters" = DEFAULT_SERVICE=XE
Done parsing command line arguments.
Oracle Net Services Configuration:
Profile configuration complete.
Host name or host name resolution is misconfigured.
linux-t1zu: linux-t1zu: Name or service not known
Check the trace file for details: /opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/netca/trace_OraHomeXE-1909219PM0220.log
Oracle Net Services configuration failed.  The exit code is 1

Parsing command line arguments:
    Parameter "orahome" = /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE
    Parameter "instype" = typical
    Parameter "inscomp" = client,oraclenet,javavm,server,ano
    Parameter "insprtcl" = tcp
    Parameter "cfg" = local
    Parameter "authadp" = NO_VALUE
    Parameter "responsefile" = /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/network/install/netca_typ.rsp
    Parameter "silent" = true
    Parameter "orahnam" = OraHomeXE
    Parameter "listenerparameters" = DEFAULT_SERVICE=XE
Done parsing command line arguments.
Oracle Net Services Configuration:
Profile configuration complete.
Host name or host name resolution is misconfigured.
linux-t1zu: linux-t1zu: Name or service not known
Check the trace file for details: /opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/netca/trace_OraHomeXE-1909219PM1730.log
Oracle Net Services configuration failed.  The exit code is 1

Parsing command line arguments:
    Parameter "orahome" = /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE
    Parameter "instype" = typical
    Parameter "inscomp" = client,oraclenet,javavm,server,ano
    Parameter "insprtcl" = tcp
    Parameter "cfg" = local
    Parameter "authadp" = NO_VALUE
    Parameter "responsefile" = /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/network/install/netca_typ.rsp
    Parameter "silent" = true
    Parameter "orahnam" = OraHomeXE
    Parameter "listenerparameters" = DEFAULT_SERVICE=XE
Done parsing command line arguments.
Oracle Net Services Configuration:
Profile configuration complete.
Host name or host name resolution is misconfigured.
linux-t1zu: linux-t1zu: Name or service not known
Check the trace file for details: /opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/netca/trace_OraHomeXE-1909219PM1809.log
Oracle Net Services configuration failed.  The exit code is 1

Parsing command line arguments:
    Parameter "orahome" = /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE
    Parameter "instype" = typical
    Parameter "inscomp" = client,oraclenet,javavm,server,ano
    Parameter "insprtcl" = tcp
    Parameter "cfg" = local
    Parameter "authadp" = NO_VALUE
    Parameter "responsefile" = /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/network/install/netca_typ.rsp
    Parameter "silent" = true
    Parameter "orahnam" = OraHomeXE
    Parameter "listenerparameters" = DEFAULT_SERVICE=XE
Done parsing command line arguments.
Oracle Net Services Configuration:
Profile configuration complete.
Oracle Net Listener Startup:
No valid IP Address returned for the host linux-t1zu.
Check the trace file for details: /opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/netca/trace_OraHomeXE-1909219PM2132.log
Oracle Net Services configuration failed.  The exit code is 1

Parsing command line arguments:
    Parameter "orahome" = /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE
    Parameter "instype" = typical
    Parameter "inscomp" = client,oraclenet,javavm,server,ano
    Parameter "insprtcl" = tcp
    Parameter "cfg" = local
    Parameter "authadp" = NO_VALUE
    Parameter "responsefile" = /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/network/install/netca_typ.rsp
    Parameter "silent" = true
    Parameter "orahnam" = OraHomeXE
    Parameter "listenerparameters" = DEFAULT_SERVICE=XE
Done parsing command line arguments.
Oracle Net Services Configuration:
Profile configuration complete.
Host name or host name resolution is misconfigured.
linux-t1zu: linux-t1zu: Name or service not known
Check the trace file for details: /opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/netca/trace_OraHomeXE-1909219PM2548.log
Oracle Net Services configuration failed.  The exit code is 1

Parsing command line arguments:
    Parameter "orahome" = /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE
    Parameter "instype" = typical
    Parameter "inscomp" = client,oraclenet,javavm,server,ano
    Parameter "insprtcl" = tcp
    Parameter "cfg" = local
    Parameter "authadp" = NO_VALUE
    Parameter "responsefile" = /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/network/install/netca_typ.rsp
    Parameter "silent" = true
    Parameter "orahnam" = OraHomeXE
    Parameter "listenerparameters" = DEFAULT_SERVICE=XE
Done parsing command line arguments.
Oracle Net Services Configuration:
Profile configuration complete.
Host name or host name resolution is misconfigured.
linux-t1zu: linux-t1zu: Name or service not known
Check the trace file for details: /opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/netca/trace_OraHomeXE-1909226AM3717.log
Oracle Net Services configuration failed.  The exit code is 1

Parsing command line arguments:
    Parameter "orahome" = /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE
    Parameter "instype" = typical
    Parameter "inscomp" = client,oraclenet,javavm,server,ano
    Parameter "insprtcl" = tcp
    Parameter "cfg" = local
    Parameter "authadp" = NO_VALUE
    Parameter "responsefile" = /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/network/install/netca_typ.rsp
    Parameter "silent" = true
    Parameter "orahnam" = OraHomeXE
    Parameter "listenerparameters" = DEFAULT_SERVICE=XE
Done parsing command line arguments.
Oracle Net Services Configuration:
Profile configuration complete.
Host name or host name resolution is misconfigured.
linux-t1zu: linux-t1zu: Name or service not known
Check the trace file for details: /opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/netca/trace_OraHomeXE-19092210AM0711.log
Oracle Net Services configuration failed.  The exit code is 1

Parsing command line arguments:
    Parameter "orahome" = /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE
    Parameter "instype" = typical
    Parameter "inscomp" = client,oraclenet,javavm,server,ano
    Parameter "insprtcl" = tcp
    Parameter "cfg" = local
    Parameter "authadp" = NO_VALUE
    Parameter "responsefile" = /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/network/install/netca_typ.rsp
    Parameter "silent" = true
    Parameter "orahnam" = OraHomeXE
    Parameter "listenerparameters" = DEFAULT_SERVICE=XE
Done parsing command line arguments.
Oracle Net Services Configuration:
Profile configuration complete.
Host name or host name resolution is misconfigured.
linux-t1zu: linux-t1zu: Name or service not known
Check the trace file for details: /opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/netca/trace_OraHomeXE-19092210AM1138.log
Oracle Net Services configuration failed.  The exit code is 1

Parsing command line arguments:
    Parameter "orahome" = /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE
    Parameter "instype" = typical
    Parameter "inscomp" = client,oraclenet,javavm,server,ano
    Parameter "insprtcl" = tcp
    Parameter "cfg" = local
    Parameter "authadp" = NO_VALUE
    Parameter "responsefile" = /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/network/install/netca_typ.rsp
    Parameter "silent" = true
    Parameter "orahnam" = OraHomeXE
    Parameter "listenerparameters" = DEFAULT_SERVICE=XE
Done parsing command line arguments.
Oracle Net Services Configuration:
Profile configuration complete.
Host name or host name resolution is misconfigured.
linux-t1zu: linux-t1zu: Name or service not known
Check the trace file for details: /opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/netca/trace_OraHomeXE-19092210AM2244.log
Oracle Net Services configuration failed.  The exit code is 1

Parsing command line arguments:
    Parameter "orahome" = /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE
    Parameter "instype" = typical
    Parameter "inscomp" = client,oraclenet,javavm,server,ano
    Parameter "insprtcl" = tcp
    Parameter "cfg" = local
    Parameter "authadp" = NO_VALUE
    Parameter "responsefile" = /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/network/install/netca_typ.rsp
    Parameter "silent" = true
    Parameter "orahnam" = OraHomeXE
    Parameter "listenerparameters" = DEFAULT_SERVICE=XE
Done parsing command line arguments.
Oracle Net Services Configuration:
Profile configuration complete.
Host name or host name resolution is misconfigured.
linux-t1zu: linux-t1zu: Name or service not known
Check the trace file for details: /opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/netca/trace_OraHomeXE-19092210AM2635.log
Oracle Net Services configuration failed.  The exit code is 1

Parsing command line arguments:
    Parameter "orahome" = /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE
    Parameter "instype" = typical
    Parameter "inscomp" = client,oraclenet,javavm,server,ano
    Parameter "insprtcl" = tcp
    Parameter "cfg" = local
    Parameter "authadp" = NO_VALUE
    Parameter "responsefile" = /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/network/install/netca_typ.rsp
    Parameter "silent" = true
    Parameter "orahnam" = OraHomeXE
    Parameter "listenerparameters" = DEFAULT_SERVICE=XE
Done parsing command line arguments.
Oracle Net Services Configuration:
Profile configuration complete.
Host name or host name resolution is misconfigured.
linux-t1zu: linux-t1zu: Name or service not known
Check the trace file for details: /opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/netca/trace_OraHomeXE-19092210AM4045.log
Oracle Net Services configuration failed.  The exit code is 1

Parsing command line arguments:
    Parameter "orahome" = /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE
    Parameter "instype" = typical
    Parameter "inscomp" = client,oraclenet,javavm,server,ano
    Parameter "insprtcl" = tcp
    Parameter "cfg" = local
    Parameter "authadp" = NO_VALUE
    Parameter "responsefile" = /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/network/install/netca_typ.rsp
    Parameter "silent" = true
    Parameter "orahnam" = OraHomeXE
    Parameter "listenerparameters" = DEFAULT_SERVICE=XE
Done parsing command line arguments.
Oracle Net Services Configuration:
Profile configuration complete.
Host name or host name resolution is misconfigured.
linux-t1zu: linux-t1zu: Name or service not known
Check the trace file for details: /opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/netca/trace_OraHomeXE-19092210AM4142.log
Oracle Net Services configuration failed.  The exit code is 1

Parsing command line arguments:
    Parameter "orahome" = /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE
    Parameter "instype" = typical
    Parameter "inscomp" = client,oraclenet,javavm,server,ano
    Parameter "insprtcl" = tcp
    Parameter "cfg" = local
    Parameter "authadp" = NO_VALUE
    Parameter "responsefile" = /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/network/install/netca_typ.rsp
    Parameter "silent" = true
    Parameter "orahnam" = OraHomeXE
    Parameter "listenerparameters" = DEFAULT_SERVICE=XE
Done parsing command line arguments.
Oracle Net Services Configuration:
Profile configuration complete.
Host name or host name resolution is misconfigured.
linux-t1zu: linux-t1zu: Name or service not known
Check the trace file for details: /opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/netca/trace_OraHomeXE-19092210AM4810.log
Oracle Net Services configuration failed.  The exit code is 1
```

I see where it first says something along the lines of

Host name or host name resolution is misconfigured.
linux-t1zu: linux-t1zu: Name or service not known

So does this mean I need to configure localhost? If it is already not?
I'm honestly pretty much lost here. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to answer my own question.
Reading [this page from the Oracle Docs in the Networking section](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E27300_01/E27308/html/vmiug-manager-requirements.html#vmiug-manager-network), I edited my /etc/hosts file as suggested, adding my hostname. At first, I did not add it in the `Short-Hostname` column and that did not work. However, going back and adding it there worked.

So like this:

In the terminal, if the output of

```
hostname
```

was `tomtom`

then my `/etc/host` file looked like this in the specific applicable portion:

```
    # IP-Address  Full-Qualified-Hostname  Short-Hostname
    #
    127.0.0.1         tomtom                   tomtom
```

Hope this answer helps any others facing this issue.

Comment: This exactly solved my problem.  You'd think Oracle would be able to give an error message such as "the hostname must be set" rather than crashing out.  Or maybe not.